# How can I space three dots uniformly as a skinny hamburger menu icon?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I want the code to show up the 3 bars, and the 3 dots to eventually be dropdown options. For some reason the 1st out of the 3 dots does not want to be spaced correctly.

```css
#dropdown {
  background: #3f51b5;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}

#bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="dot"></div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="dot"></div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="dot"></div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Picture of what is returned:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a hard thing to do with floats.
A possible solution could be to wrap the dots and the bars within a div.
Afterwards you can position those wrapping divs in the style you like.
I used flexbox for this in the following snippet.

```css
#dropdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #3f51b5;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

p.s.: you should use the keyword `class` instead of `id` for repeating elements. This might still work, but is considered bad practice and might break javascript implementations using that `id`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with one element for each:

```css
#dropdown {
  background: #3f51b5;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(5px 5px at center, white 57%, transparent 61%) top/10px 10px;
  float: right;
}

#bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top/100% 3px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/100% 3px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/100% 3px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Here is another idea:

```css
#dropdown {
  background: #3f51b5;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:
    0 10px 0 #fff,
    0 20px 0 #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  float: right;
}

#bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 23px;
  padding:7px 0;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border-top:3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
  background:#fff content-box;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Also like this with pseudo element:

```css
#dropdown {
  background: #3f51b5;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  float: right;
  position:relative;
}
#dot:before,
#dot:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:inherit;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  background:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
  top:-8px;
}
#dot:after {
  bottom:-8px;
  top:auto;
}
#bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background:#fff;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}
#bar:before,
#bar:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:inherit;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  background:inherit;
  top:-8px;
}
#bar:after {
  bottom:-8px;
  top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both nice approaches, but at certain page zoom levels the rendering is less than perfect (uneven spacing for the first / uneven bar height for the second).

Comment: I don't see that in Chrome. Which browser?

Comment: Chrome 71, Win10 x64. Maybe something I have to learn to accept, it happens for all your variants (at certain page zoom levels), also for the other answer + for the html/css from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like if you want to check for first specific dot

```
#dropdown div:first-child { 
  position:relative;
  top:4px
}
```